# Select2 Laravel Json

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

I've been playing with this setup for a while now but I can't get the results to return to the select box.

See my streamlined code for question below, everything is initialized however I'm just not getting anything back.

Code:
**JS.**

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
  ajax: {
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/ajax/staff',
    delay: 250
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control js-data-example-ajax">
   <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('ajax/staff', 'APIController@staff');
```

**Controller**

```
public function staff()
    {
        $staff = staff::all();
        return $staff;
    }
```

Comment: where you get stucked?

Comment: Sorry, I get stuck on outputting the json from the API staff().. It's almost like im not returning anything to the select

Comment: you can make a foreach in staff function in which append a vairable like $output.="<option>your value</option>" and outside loop echo the variable and in ajax call put the success function and take response and append into your select input..visit http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/   like$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( response) {
    $( "#results" ).append( response);
  });

Comment: Try `return response()->json($staff)` and that should return it as json.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
  public function staff()
        {
            $staff = staff::all();
             echo json_encode($staff);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller isn't returning JSON.

Try it this way:

```
public function staff()
{
   $staff = staff::all();
   return response()->json($staff);
}
```